# What role does the Screen Actors Guild play in controlling credits?

Tags: credits, film-industry, directors

In this [article](http://www.neatorama.com/2018/01/31/Airplane-The-Funniest-Movie-Ever) about *Airplane!*, the author states:

> The Zucker brothers and Jim Abrahams had a tough time with the Screen Actors Guild in trying to get their proper three director billing when the film was released, but eventually prevailed.

In general, what role does the Screen Actors Guild play in controlling credits?

In this specific case, what was the issue with crediting three directors?

Comment: My first question would be *`<citation required>`*

Comment: The **Directors Guild** generally has jurisdiction here and they generally only allow **one** named person as a director. Exceptions are made for regular partneeships (Coen Bros, Warchowskis etc) but that might not have been the case in 1980.

Comment: The "one director" rule dates to 1978 and there were 15 requests for waivers between 1979 and 1989, with 10 of those granted by the Guild. So it was definitely the case in 1980 that multiple-director credit exceptions were a thing. (src: https://www.dga.org/Craft/DGAQ/All-Articles/0405-May-2004/Singularity-of-Vision.aspx)